# Flipping the viewport in Vulkan

Tags: glsl, viewport, vulkan

From the spec:

> VK_KHR_maintenance1
>
> Allow negative height to be specified in the slink::VkViewport::height field to perform y-inversion of the
> clip-space to framebuffer-space transform. This allows apps to avoid
> having to use gl_Position.y = -gl_Position.y in shaders also targeting
> other APIs.

My physical device supports version `1.0.42` and I have enabled the `VK_KHR_maintenance1`.
I do not get any validation error/warning when I do a negative height in the `VkViewport` struct.

```
vkCmdSetViewport(vkContext.commandBuffer, 0, 1, &viewport);
```

However I do not see anything on the screen either, its black, if I remove the negative value in the `viewport` everything is rendered as expected. Do I need to do anything else to flip the viewport with the `VK_KHR_maintenance1 extension`? I am just rendering a red quad on the screen, with a fullscreen viewport.

```
VkViewport viewport = {};
viewport.x = 0.0f;
viewport.y = 0.0f;
viewport.width = 1024.0f;
viewport.height = -1024.0f;
viewport.minDepth = 0.0f;
viewport.maxDepth = 1.0f;
vkCmdSetViewport(vkContext.commandBuffer, 0, 1, &viewport);
```

Vertex shader:

```
void main() {
        vec4 positions[3] = {
        vec4(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0),
        vec4(3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0),
        vec4(-1.0, 3.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    };
    gl_Position = positions[gl_VertexIndex % 3];
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
void main() {
    outFragColor = vec4(1,0,0,1);
}
```

Comment: "*However I do not see anything on the screen either*" What are you rendering? What does your VS look like? What does your projection matrix look like? What does `viewport` contain? And so on. We can't know what's going on without seeing your code.

Comment: @NicolBolas Added vertex and fragment shader

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just go through the math. You have all of the numbers, and the specification explicitly lays it all out.

The equations for the Y component of the framebuffer-space vertex coordinate are:

```
Yf = (Py / 2) Yd + Oy
Oy = viewport.y + viewport.height / 2.0
Py = viewport.height
```

Where `Yf` is the framebuffer-space Y component and `Yd` is the NDC-space Y component.

If you plug in a positive `height` of 1024, what numbers do you get? For a `Yd` of -1, you get a `Yf` of 0.0. For a `Yd` of 3, you get a `Yf` of 2048.

In Vulkan, the "natural" viewport transform maps NDC-space by putting -1 at the `viewport.x/y`, with 1 at the `viewport.width/height`. And remember: Vulkan's images have a top-left origin, with positive values going down and to the right. So the `Yf` of 0.0 is at the top, and the `Yf` of 2048 is off the bottom of the screen. Therefore, the triangle is (partly) in the visible area of the view port.

Given that, what happens when you use a negative `height`? The math doesn't change; just the results. For a `Yd` of -1, you get a `Yf` of 0.0, much like before. For a `Yd` of 3, you get a `Yf` of -2048.

What does that look like? Well, the *meaning* of the viewport hasn't changed; just the numbers. That means that the visible area of the framebuffer image is still at the top left, going *down*. And a value of -2048 is therefore *above* the viewport.

In short, a negative height flips the viewport. But that flips it at the *viewport origin*, not at the center of the screen. The viewport origin is at the top-left going down and to the right. And therefore, flipping it will flip everything that was previously visible off of the screen. You're now looking at a different area of the screen, which in your case was blank.

If you want to flip everything around the *center* of the viewport, then you need to adjust the `viewport.y` to compensate for the negative height. Specifically, it needs to be the positive height.

Comment: Thank you, a really good explanation, I thought Vulkan was flipping the viewport plus moving the origin behind the scene when you put in a negative height:)

Comment: The formulas cited by Nicol Bolas may be found in [Vulkan 1.2.148, Chapter 23](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2/html/chap24.html).